# Prim's Algorithm with std::vector and std::queue , What is wrong with my code?

Tags: c++

I am trying sort edges in Prim's Algorithm using `STL` and overloading operator `()` , But I am getting runtime error `Invalid operator` and `Invalid Heap`.

When I compile my code in `CodeBlocks` everything's working but Visual Studio 2015 displayed runtime errors. What should I do?

```
struct edge {                                                            
    int cost;                                           
    int start;               
    int end;                                    
};

struct sorting { 
    bool operator() (const edge &a, const edge &b)
    {
        if (a.cost<b.cost) return false;
        else return true;
    }

};

priority_queue <  edge , vector <edge> , sorting> queue; 

edge tree[1005];

int T[1000][1000];
int G[1005][1005];

bool ISIT[1005];
string STRINGS[1005]; 
int ID[40005];
int howmany = 0;
int howmanyneigh[1005];

void PRIM() {
    int w = 1; 
    ISIT[w] = 1; 
    edge K;
    howmany++; 

    for (int i = 0; i<howmanyneigh[w]; i++) {
        K.start = w;
        K.end = G[w][i];
        K.cost = T[w][G[w][i]];
        queue.push(K); 
    }


    while (howmany<N) 
        edge b;
        b = queue.top();
        queue.pop(); 
        while (ISIT[b.end]) { 
            b = queue.top(); 
            queue.pop(); 
        }

     ISIT[b.end] = 1; 
        tree[howmany - 1] = b; 

        for (int i = 0; i<howmanyneigh[b.end]; i++) { 
            K.start = b.end;
            K.end = G[b.end][i];
            K.cost = T[b.end][G[b.end][i]];
            queue.push(K);
        }
        howmany++;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, would you kindly step through a debugger and pinpoint the relevant code to your problem. This goes along the lines of providing a [mcve]

Comment: In addition, debugger stopped in `while` loops...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have a problem in your `sorting` comparator. This comparator should [provide](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare) [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings). One of the requirements for strict weak ordering is that `comp(a, a) == false`. Change your `sorting::operator()` from

```
 if (a.cost<b.cost) return false;
 else return true;
```

to:

```
 if (a.cost>b.cost) return true;
 else return false;
```

or simply:

```
 return a.cost > b.cost;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! It's working. Wow!!! One stupid line... Thank you!!!

Comment: @MMat if this worked for you, consider marking it as answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: or, more succinctly `return a.cost > b.cost;`

Comment: @Caleth Sure, I just wanted to make it similar to the original code. I'll add this to the answer, thanks!